# Spoofed email: whose fault is it?

Tags: email, email-spoofing, spf, dmarc

My relative received an email from a bill they were expecting to pay. So they paid said bill.

Only problem is: it was a spoofed email, and the real bill only came in later.

I checked the email on the email platform (Outlook) and **there was no indication that it was a spoofed email**. I checked the email source code, and I verified the spoofed email did not pass Dkim nor Dmarc tests. `Authenticated sender` field was different than the `From:` field.

But it passed SPF test (`domain of abc.com designates XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX as permitted sender`, however, `abc.com` is the domain of the hacker, not the company's domain), so Outlook still accepted the email.

Is the billing company that was impersonated liable in this case, because it was an outside hacker that sent a spoofed email, but it seems the email was validated by their SPF test and their server was not configured to invalidate such email.

Comment: Does *company* represent your mail provider, or the company that was impersonated? In any case, SPF, DKIM, DMARC, are more of security features someone may implement to reduce spoofing than a contractual obligation. Of course, it depends on the contract you have with the other parties.

Comment: company is the billing company, that was impersonated...

Comment: _"SPF, DKIM, DMARC, are more of security features someone may implement to reduce spoofing than a contractual obligation"_ if that's the case, it is not viable to use email anymore, and we should go back to physical mail, right? Because then no email we receive can be trusted

Comment: Do you consider physical mail to be more secure? From experience, these mechanisms are implemented to reduce risks, not to engage in any additional liability. Moreover, it is your email provider that delivered to you an email that failed DKIM and DMARC tests.

Comment: In your last sentence, if 'the company' refers to the impersonated company and 'their' also refers to the impersonated company, then the answer to your question is no - because these spoofed emails never passed through the impersonated company's mail servers.  They were sent directly from the spoofer's outgoing mail server to your relative's incoming mail provider (Outlook).  However, you could argue that Outlook could have done a better job at flagging this message as suspicious, being that the envelope sender (which SPF is based on) did not match the sender in the message header.

Comment: I see here on the headers it has `X-Microsoft-Antispam-Mailbox-Delivery: ... ;dest:J;RF:JunkEmail`, and also `dmarc=fail action=quarantine`. Does that mean this email was probably received on the spam folder?

Comment: This looks like a header that Outlook appended upon receipt of the message.  From reading it, it looks like Outlook's spam filter detected that the message was junkmail based on the DMARC failure (possibly in part because the envelope sender did not match the sender in the message headers).  But, only Outlook could tell you whether or not their system routed the message to the user's spam folder.

Comment: The mismatch between the domain used in the `SPF` check and the `FROM` address is quite normal. The domain that `SPF` checks is the one in the `Return-Path` address, where bounces are sent. If you use a 3rd party app that tracks bounces, these bounces need to end up there. It can be done more elegantly, but is is still common practice. DMARC is there to ensure that either `SPF` or `DKIM` checks are aligned with the `FROM` address. The billing company published a `DMARC` Quarantine policy for when authentication fails. The headers indicate the email was delivered to the Junk folder as a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A scam like that is a crime, and what happens with those is out of scope here.  It is the fault of the criminal.  But answering the question this implies: what is one supposed to do about it?

First, advise users that while they can trust the bill notification, the payment link is best not used.  There are two options to pay the bill online:

- Type the URL of the biller's website (or use a bookmark), check the bill amount, and pay it there
- Add the biller as a recipient or e-bill in online banking (using information the bank provides, information from a mailed bill, or information from a bill downloaded from the biller's website, not from email), and pay the bill there

This will fix the problem.  Your relative will not get scammed by this again if they do this.  It's equivalent to a commonly used control in corporate accounts payable departments to avoid exactly this type of scam.

Second, you didn't post the SPF policy, and it sounds like it's wrong and the company should reconfigure it.

Third, spam detection is a guess, not a hard and fast rule, and although it is silly and needless, many senders will send important mail with broken security headers.  But one could argue Outlook's spam filter could be improved here.

Comment: I agree that any payment request via email should be treated with suspicion.
On your "second" argument: Even without posting the exact SPF policy, we can determine the check passed, "on the domain of the hacker". So, SPF of the company was not the issue.
On your "third": Spam detection can seem like a black box. But is simply a rating system where certain factors increase the likelihood of a message being SPAM. Outlook detected the email as being SPAM and placed it in the JUNK folder, as the OP commented. While SPAM detection may be opaque, in my opinion Email Authentication is not.